# What does "shuffle" do in fit_generator in keras?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I manually built a data generator that yields a tuple of `[input, target]` each call. I set my generator to shuffle the training samples every epoch. Then I use `fit_generator` to call my `generator`, but confuse at the "shuffle" argument in this function:

```
fit_generator(self, generator, steps_per_epoch=None, epochs=1, verbose=1, callbacks=None, validation_data=None, validation_steps=None, class_weight=None, max_queue_size=10, workers=1, use_multiprocessing=False, shuffle=True, initial_epoch=0)
```

From Keras [API](https://keras.io/models/sequential/#fit_generator):

> **shuffle**: Whether to shuffle the order of the batches at the beginning
>   of each epoch. Only used with instances of Sequence
>   (keras.utils.Sequence)

I thought "shuffle" should be the job of the `generator`. How can it shuffle the order of the batches when my custom `generator` decides which batch to be output in each iteration?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As the documentation you quoted says, the *shuffle* argument is only relevant for a generator that implements keras.utils.Sequence.

If you are using a "simple" generator (such as keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator, or your own custom non-Sequence generator), than that generator implements a method that return a single batch (using yield - you can learn more about it in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do)). Therefore, only the generator itself controls what batch is returned.

[keras.utils.Sequence](https://keras.io/utils/#sequence) was introduced to support multiprocessing:

> Sequence are a safer way to do multiprocessing. This structure
>   guarantees that the network will only train once on each sample per
>   epoch which is not the case with generators.

To that end, you need to implement a method that return a batch by a batch index (which allows synchronization of multiple workers): `__getitem__(self, idx)`. If you enable the *shuffle* argument, the `__getitem__` method will be invoked with indexes in a random order.

However, you may also set it to false, and shuffle yourself by implementing the `on_epoch_end` method.

Comment: so what happens if I use my own custom non-sequence generator and set _shuffle=True_ in _fit-generator_?

Comment: Nothing happens. If you look at the source: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/3b444513b52cf05e7d40f2ffdb7ab7283bb2ce06/keras/engine/training.py#L2168, The argument is only used when your generator is a Sequence.

Comment: In the method __getitem_(...), is there a way to know which worker (thread) id is grabbing that particular batch (identified by "idx")? The motivation for asking is I want to spread the workload across 2 workers constructing a separate dataset (e.g. negative samples). Ideally, this should be done in on_epoch_end, but it probably won't be done by multi-processes?