# How to improve training performance of model.fit() with generators?

Tags: python, tensorflow, generator, tf.keras

Normally when I train models with tensorflow, I just feed my entire data set to the model training (Scenario 1). However, from time to time this data set is to large to fit into my GPU. For that reason I wanted to use generators and just load batch after batch into the GPU (Scenario 2). Both scenarios run perfectly fine but the normal fit without generators produces significantly better results. How can I use generators and yield the "same" result as when I'm loading the whole data set?

**Scenario 1:** parsing whole data set

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
import h5py

# creating a model and stuff
model = Model(...)
model.compile(...)

with h5py.File("db.h5py", 'r') as db_:
   model.fit(db_["X_train"][...],
             db_["Y_train"][...],
             epochs=60,
             batch_size=256,
             shuffle=True,
             validation_data=(db_["X_val"][...], db_["Y_val"][...])
             )
```

**Scenario 2:** Using generators

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
import h5py

with h5py.File("db.h5py", 'r') as db_:
   x = db_["X_train"][...]
   y = db_["Y_train"][...]
   x_val = db_["X_val"][...]
   y_val = db_["Y_val"][...]


class DataGen(tf.keras.utils.Sequence):
   def __init__(self, index_map, batch_size, args):
       if args == "training":
           self.X = x
           self.y = y
       else:
           self.X = x_val
           self.y = y_val
       self.index_map = index_map
       self.batch_size = batch_size

   def __getitem__(self, index):
       X_batch = self.X[self.index_map[
                        index * self.batch_size: (index + 1) * self.batch_size
                        ]]

       y_batch = self.y[self.index_map[
                        index * self.batch_size: (index + 1) * self.batch_size
                        ]]
       return X_batch, y_batch

   def __len__(self):
       return len(self.index_map) // self.batch_size


train_gen = DataGen(np.arange(x.shape[0]), 256, "training")
val_gen = DataGen(np.arange(x_val.shape[0]), 256, "validation")

# creating a model and stuff
model = Model(...)
model.compile(...)

model.fit(train_gen,
         epochs=60,
         steps_per_epoch=x.shape[0] // 256,
         shuffle=True,
         validation_data=val_gen
         )
```

**Generator case 4:** Same as Scenario 2 + `on_epoch_end()` method

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
import h5py

with h5py.File("db.h5py", 'r') as db_:
   x = db_["X_train"][...]
   y = db_["Y_train"][...]
   x_val = db_["X_val"][...]
   y_val = db_["Y_val"][...]


class DataGen(tf.keras.utils.Sequence):
   def __init__(self, index_map, batch_size, args):
       if args == "training":
           self.X = x
           self.y = y
       else:
           self.X = x_val
           self.y = y_val
       self.index_map = index_map
       self.batch_size = batch_size

   def __getitem__(self, index):
       X_batch = self.X[self.index_map[
                        index * self.batch_size: (index + 1) * self.batch_size
                        ]]

       y_batch = self.y[self.index_map[
                        index * self.batch_size: (index + 1) * self.batch_size
                        ]]
       return X_batch, y_batch

   def __len__(self):
       return len(self.index_map) // self.batch_size

   def on_epoch_end(self):
       'Updates indexes after each epoch'
       np.random.shuffle(self.index_map)


train_gen = DataGen(np.arange(x.shape[0]), 256, "training")
val_gen = DataGen(np.arange(x_val.shape[0]), 256, "validation")

# creating a model and stuff
model = Model(...)
model.compile(...)

model.fit(train_gen,
         epochs=60,
         steps_per_epoch=x.shape[0] // 256,
         shuffle=True,
         validation_data=val_gen
         )
```

#### Performance results

This plot shows predicting performance of the test dataset. Each boxplot is comprised of the evaluation metrics of 10 model runs with different hyperparameter configurations.
[image: Performance]

- Generator case 1: model.fit() with `batch_size` argument
- Generator case 2: model.fit() without `batch_size` argument
- Generator case 3: model.fit() without `batch_size` argument, with `steps_per_epoch` argument
- Generator case 4: Same as "Generator case 3" + shuffle module `on_epoch_end()` within `DataGen` class

#### UPDATE: It seems like 'Generator case 4' solves the specified problem. However its unclear what the `shuffle` argument does when using generators.

Comment: What do you mean with "produces significantly better results"? Additionally, beware that `shuffle` in `.fit()` is ignored when given generators. An alternative to `tf.keras.utils.Sequence` would be `tf.data.Dataset`, which scales better and could yield better performance.

Comment: This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49834514) states that the shuffle argument is respected when an instance of `tf.keras.utils.Sequence` is used. With better performance I mean that when I'm testing my trained model with another data set, that my evaluation metric (e.g. mse) is much better, so much that it is not a random fluctuation.

Comment: The docs in the link are from `fit_generator()` (not `.fit()`), which is deprecated since version 2.1. In the current [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit), it is not that much clearer I admit ("This argument is ignored when x is a generator or an object of tf.data.Dataset."). It should include `Sequences`, as they are no generators (I forgot), and they are mentioned separately otherwise. I tested it and it appears that shuffling works indeed on `Sequences`.

Comment: Also, you should not mix `Sequence` (or generators, or `tf.data.Datasets`) with `batch_size` in `.fit()`. I don't know the behaviour, but the docs state explicitly that `batch_size` should be `None` (default) with that inputs. Funny that this is the best case for the `Sequences`.

Comment: How did you test that the shuffling is working, I'm having trouble extracting the values from the Sequence (is it a sequence and not a generator?) ? Still I have no glue, what is causing the different behaviour. Something must be different from `model.fit()` with the whole data set. Maybe it is how the validation set is handled, I will look into this.

Comment: It's a pretty ham-fisted approach which you can see [here](https://gist.github.com/mahenning/fc0f3074fd425f1b128306a98a051eea). The metric has the (I think) mean of `y_true` per batch, and the callback prints it every batch. You can see that the first `mode.fit()`, the metric values are the same per epoch (the first 5 `y_true mean` values are the same as the next 5), but the second `model.fit()` the metric values change for every epoch, which means that the shuffle parameter in .fit() has to work.

Comment: Thank you, that is a practical code snippet. While it seems that the shuffling is working, I'm not really satisfied with the shuffle result. The last batch for example has always the same mean value, which i would not expect when the batches a random.

Comment: Metrics usually add up over the epoch and are reset and the end of the epoch (and also printed). I think what we see are not the per-batch values, but the added-up values (in batch 2 it is batch 1-2, batch 3 is batch 1-3), which represent the whole dataset at the end of an epoch. This would explain why that number is the ~same as for the last batch of the non-shuffled run.

Comment: Yes that makes sense. Do you know by any chance if the validation set is also shuffled when `shuffle=True` in `model.fit()`? I would want to avoid that.

Comment: The docs state "whether to shuffle the training data before each epoch", so it should be train data only. Interestingly, it is also stated that shuffle "Has no effect when steps_per_epoch is not None. ", so I'd be careful with `steps_per_epoch` if you don't need it. Besides, it does not make a difference for the validation data if it's shuffled or not.

Comment: I updated my post, it seems like the shuffle argument is not working properly. Can give me a link to the docs you are referring to, because the docs I'm using doesn't state what you said about the `steps_per_epoch`

Comment: It's in the official Tensorflow docs: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit

Comment: Regarding your update with shuffle and generators: It does nothing, generators can't be shuffled, as they generate samples on-the-go and has no real "list" of all values. `Sequences` are no generators, as they can be indexed for example, or you can get the same sample two times. They should be able to get shuffled also, but it seems that `Sequence` has to handle that itself.